# selecting elements in WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How do I select only the `Published DateTime webelement and click it?

My HTML code

```
<tr>
<th scope="col">
...........
</th>
<th scope="col">
...........
</th>
<th scope="col">
...........
</th>
<th scope="col">
...........
</th>
........
<th scope="col">
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$AddControl1$gv','Sort$PublishDateTime')">Published DateTime</a>
</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Published DateTime")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String cssSelector= "tr>th[scope='col']>a:contains('Published DateTime')"
```

first way:

```
driver.findElement(By.css(cssSelector)).click()
```

second way(using js):

```
public void jsClick(String css){
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+css+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
}
jsClick(cssSelector)
```

Hope this works for you)

Comment: thanks for your reply, `Published DateTime` is not the last element i have more elements but just thought to paste minimal html code... so back to the question, so what will be the css? since i dont have css

Comment: edited. you can alway check css selector in firepath(firebug addon in ffox). you are welcome)

Comment: I checked  CSS selector and I have the same for all and which makes me wonder how would I go after specific txt I am trying to validate?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to validate text you can use the following approach:
- locating element as I mentioned above:

```
String cssSelector= "tr>th[scope='col']>a:contains('Published DateTime')"
```

**1st way of getting validating text:**

```
String txt=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText().trim();
//validating 
Assert.assertTrue(txt.equals("blablabla"));
```

**2nd way of getting validating text:**

```
publiv String getTextByJs(String css){
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+css+"\");");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.text().toString();")       ;


       String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
}
String txt=getTextByJs(cssSelector);
Assert.assertTrue(txt.equals("blablabla"));
```

enjoy)

Answer (score 0):

`driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Published DateTime")).Click();` is a correct answer. In addition, if you are using javascript-selenium-webdriver. Suggest you use https://npmjs.org/package/webdriver-helper for more friendly apis.

`driver.link(':contains("Published DateTime")').click()` could help you.